# In affine geometry, will "promoting" a linearly independent set of n vectors and a linearly independent set of n linear forms determine a metric?

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces, affine-geometry

This is something which always baffled me about discussions of affine geometry.  I was told "you have no metric available".  But it seems obvious that there *is* always a metric available.

In n-dimensional affine geometry, will "promoting" a linearly independent set of n vectors and a linearly independent set of n linear forms determine a metric?

I am specifically asking about geometry of real number scalars.  By a metric, I mean a symmetric non-degenerate bilinear form.  The answer seems to obviously be yes. ... But once you start using your metric you are no longer doing affine geometry.

The original statement of my question was intentionally limited because I didn't want to submit a specific method and have that become the subject of discussion.  But for the sake of concreteness, here is one method I had in mind.

We can always decree our given linearly independent spanning vector set to be orthonormal. Since affine geometry has no inherent definition of orthogonality, and no means of comparing non-parallel displacements, there is nothing to contradict that choice.

Using our fiat orthonormal basis

$$\left\{ \hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{i}\backepsilon1\le i\le n\right\},$$

we determine those $n$ linear combinations of our given one-forms such that

$$\hat{\omega}^{j}\left[\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{i}\right]=\delta_{i}^{j}.$$

With vectors expressed as
$$\mathfrak{v}=\hat{\mathfrak{e}}_{i}v^{i},$$

and one-forms expressed as

$$\overset{\sim}{w}=w_{j}\hat{\omega}^{j},$$

we define the dual of a vector by

$$\overset{\sim}{v}=\sum_{j}\hat{\omega}^{j}\hat{\omega}^{j}\left[\mathfrak{v}\right]=\sum_{j}\hat{\omega}^{j}v^{j}=v_{j}\hat{\omega}^{j}.$$

We now have the standard Pythagorean metric:

$$\overset{\sim}{v}\left[\mathfrak{v}\right]=v_{j}\delta_{i}^{j}v^{i}=\delta{}_{ij}v^{i}v^{j}$$.

Comment: Of course, you can endow an affine space with such a metric, but then you are doing Euclidean geometry, not affine geometry. One is strictly included in the other: you can see this with the fact that, given an affine space $\mathcal{E}$ and a positive definite bilinear form $q$, $\mathrm{Isom}(\mathcal{E},q) \subsetneq  \mathrm{Aff}(\mathcal{E})$. Euclidean geometry is much more rigid: in the euclidean plane, whereas there are only three classes of conics under the action of the affine group, there are infinitly many of them under the action of the Euclidean group!

Comment: The positive definite part was something I was still contemplating.  You apparently noticed my conspicuous omission.

Comment: For other non-degenerate quadratic forms, things are similar, unless the isometry groups are not compact. They are still strictly included in the affine group.

Comment: I don't believe my method can produce a non-definite (AKA indefinite) metric.

Comment: Could you give details on your method? You just said you made a choice, but not explained how you used the preferred basis.

Comment: @Didier my method was obvious until I thought about it.  I admit there are a number of ways to proceed.  I was just looking at the operation of a linear form on a vector as an inner product.  From that, I intuitively knew I had a metric at hand.  Without adding further conditions, there is no way to designate a "negative dimension".  But this is beyond the scope of my original question.

Comment: How would you combined a basis + a basis of the dual space at once to define such a metric? In my opinion, they are separatly useful but together there is too much information. E.g, a basis will define an orthonormal basis and thus a metric. Linearly independant linear forms will define a dual basis that could be used as an orthonormal basis. With both, you could get stuck in your choice I guess. Also, you could define negative dimension by setting, I don't know, $q = {\ell_1}^2 - {\ell_2}^2$ on an affine plane with $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ linearly independant. There are so much ways to do these

Comment: @Didier https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/43006 (rife with typos) https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-97861-6

Comment: I find your question and your comments really vague and elusive. I'm sorry but I am not going to read 517 pages without any indication in order to understand something you did not state clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "yes". Any allowable coordinate system in affine space can be designated as orthonormal.  This identifies an equivalence class of coordinate systems and a subgroup of the group of affine transformations having the property that the resulting coordinate system is also orthonormal relative to the original arbitrarily designated orthonormal system.

A different designation of a coordinate system not in that subgroup will identify different relatively orthonormal equivalence class, rendering the members of previously identified equivalence class relatively oblique.

Apparently what distinguishes affine geometry from Euclidean geometry is that there is some particular equivalence class of relatively orthonormal systems which is "true".